# Need both to disable a checkbox and make it look as it is disabled (style))

Tags: angular, disabled-input

I have an HTML element (input of type checkbox), and in my template, I've added the following to the mentioned HTML element:

```
<input type="checkbox" *ngFor="let status of statuses"
[class.disabled]="status==='Ready' && settings.length > 0 && !settings.includes(status)" [disabled]="status==='Ready' && settings.length > 0 && !settings.includes(status)">
```

Now, everything works perfectly and exactly the way I want, but I need to duplicate a very long condition:

```
"status==='Ready' && settings.length > 0 && !settings.includes(status)"
```

Is there a shorter way to do it?

I can't use only disabled, because then the checkbox would be disabled indeed, but it will look as if it is active and enabled (even though it can't be checked).

I can't use only class.disabled, because then the checkbox would look as disabled, but if I try to check it, I will succeed (it only looks as disabled, but it actually enabled).

Any suggestion, please?

Comment: Add `{
    cursor: default;
    pointer-events: none;
}` to the disabled class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Instead of checking all the condition "status==='Ready' && settings.length > 0 && !settings.includes(status)" in template, use component for this.

you can write a simple function in the component which return either true or false based on the condition
       function disableCheckBox() {
        if(status==='Ready' && settings.length > 0 && !settings.includes(status))
           return true;
        return false;
        }
and in the template 
    <input type="checkbox" *ngFor="let status of statuses"
    [class.disabled]="disableCheckBox()" [disabled]="disableCheckBox()">

Or Else create a single variable for that
```

Comment: Please note that status is the variable of ngFor and it is not a property in my ts file. I mean, I don't have a reference to the status variable you have written in your suggested disbleCheckBox function

Comment: You can pass that status as an arguments in the function

Comment: Thank you, @Ankur Jain
This is definitely a more elegant solution. Now, if I have to change the condition, I'll have to change it in one place and not multiple places.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe instead of the .disabled-selector in your css-file you could use

```
input[type="text"]:disabled { ... your css rules ...}
```

If yes, you could remove the [class.disabled]="..." in your html.